# Making realtime maps for coastal zone using ArcMap with added layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I would like to make the best mapping services for clients for exact mapping layers for High tide line and low tide line ( which the data is being collected physically in x,y format) with this data should I make maps in ArcMap 10 with desired layers and desired scale for presenting the stylish maps.

Can you provide a step by step procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Temporal Mapping Services are covered on the ESRI Website

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_temporal_data_management_and_visualization/005z00000021000000/

Important that you understand the TIME construction - Use ROWS rather than columns etc.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Best_practices_for_storing_temporal_data/005z00000005000000/

This can be applied to ArcGIS Server 10 for Temporal Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

For what country?

Has this not already been mapped before for your region?

Do you have an accurate coastline outline for your region?
 - How was this coastline derived?

You mention it is being surveyed with XY locations of each LWM/HWM
- Would really need to get more info around this data collection before giving you a good answer.

A crude approach which is just me thinking off the top of my head.
I will try and put some more thought into this tomm when I have more time.

- first get this XY data into ArcGIS and get it [plotted out](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000.htm).
- Get a DTM for the region.  Ideally a DTM with good bathymetric heights as well.
- Using Spatial Analyst create an interpolation of the XYZ data (Z being the attribute of either the HWM or the LWM).  Perhaps use the inner coastline polygon layer as a barrier (?)  I would 1st sugggest doing an Inverse Distance Weighted interpolation, setting the max distance based on how far your points are apart.
- Using the grid calculator, subtract the DTM with the interpolated layer you created above.
- Remove any negative values from the result.
- This should give you a layer with the perimeter being the LWM/HWM depending on which results you interpolated above.  You could then create a polygon extent of this grid and this would be your result.

I imagine this won't be the best answer (not in its current state) but perhaps it will cause others to suggest a better, more accurate answer.  Or the author to give more info...

TBH, at the mo, I am reluctant to put more effort/time in until the question is phrased better.